# JQuery hover event handler running too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, pause

I have a dropdown menu that activates on mouse hover. It has a animation which takes 200ms to finish and 200ms again if you take your mouse off for it to reset back.

If you run your mouse over the dropdown and off really fast for 10 seconds for example and then move your mouse away the dropdown will constantly dropdown and back up until it has done it as many times as your mouse was on the dropdown.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```js
var dropdown = function() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $('.inbutton').animate({
            top: '-188px'
        }, 200);
        $('.dr2button').animate({
            top: '0px'
        }, 200);
    }, function() {
        $('.inbutton').animate({
            top: '-122px'
        }, 200);
        $('.dr2button').animate({
            top: '-61px'
        }, 200);
    });
};


$(document).ready(dropdown);
```

Comment: Please edit to fix snippet. Currently displays nothing.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: You can decide everytime a mouseover or mouseout event occurs whether to animate or not based on a variable which you can manipulate when the animation completes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preppend the `stop()` function to `animate()`

```
    $('.inbutton').stop().animate({
        top: '-122px'
    }, 200);
```

Make this in all animate functions.

More info:

https://api.jquery.com/stop/